# AutoCompleteTextView background

Tags: java, android

I'm working on my registration fragment but somehow having a problem on one of my TextInputlayout, how do I remove the black background in my AutoCompleteTextView?

here's my code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:textColorHint="#7E7C7C"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#24d95f"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    app:endIconTint="#24d95f"
    app:hintTextColor="#24d95f"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_confirmpassword">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:inputType="none" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you say what ```android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"``` does ?

Comment: android:background="@null"